# how to have live text between 2 fixed backgrounds for the header

Tags: css

I would like to have a fixed header, all of the content in the header should be fixed at the top. I am having trouble because I have 2 backgrounds that will sandwich some content. So basically if you look at the code snippet, i would like 1-header-holidaybg.png on top then the paragraph then 3-header-holidaybg.png and after that is the main content that is not fixed and scrolls behind the header. There cannot be any space between the background and paragraph like i have now but I am having a lot of trouble accomplishing this.

```css
header {
 position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
z-index: 100;
}

#headerbg {
 background: url("https://secure.feedingamerica.org/images/content/pagebuilder/1-header-holidaybg.png") no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
   background-size: 100%;
     height: 190px;
  }
#hbottom { 
background: url("https://secure.feedingamerica.org/images/content/pagebuilder/3-header-holidaybg.png") no-repeat;
min-height: 60px;
}

.container {
 margin: 0px 120px;
}

header p {
background: #fff;
padding: 10px 0px;
color: #333;

}



#main-content {
margin-top: 45%;
padding-top: 20px;
background: url("https://secure.feedingamerica.org/images/content/pagebuilder/holiday-bg.png") repeat;
color: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
<div id="headerbg">
    
</div>
    <p>this content should display below the 1-header-holidaybg.png backbround but above the 3-header-holidaybg.png background</p>
<div id="hbottom"></div>
</header>
<div id="main-content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZXPYoK) for you that may be what you're looking for.

- Move the `background: #fff` up to the `header` element. This prevents the items scrolling behind from showing through.
- Add a `position: relative` to the `main-content` div and align it to the top using `top: 0`. This will position the container relative to its parent container, which in this case is the `body`. (I added a `height: 2000px` just for testing)
- I'd also suggest tossing in a container inside `main-content` that will house your paragraph text; `paragraphContent` for this example. You'll then want to add `position: relative` to that container. This makes the section a little more dynamic so you can add more content without having to worry about styling the paragraphs too much.

The unfortunate part of `position: fixed` is that since it takes items out of the standard flow of the document, things can easily be overlapped, so you want to take this into consideration when hitting smaller viewports. In your example, the paragraph text in the header wraps to multiple lines on small viewports, which pushes the background down over the main content. To prevent this is the pen, I threw in a media query that kicks in when the viewport is under 415px.